# Can a paper be submitted to a journal first and then to a conference?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, paper-submission

We have finished the work and are now planning to submit it. We are targeting a journal. But then we found the journal is only six pages. Six pages only allow us to write down our brief idea and some conclusions. So we have to omit a lot of details in the paper. But we also want to publish those details. Is it possible that we submit the work to the journal first and then extend the journal paper with the details and submit it to another conference? Are there any better solutions? Thank you!

Comment: How about a journal that has a larger limit?

Comment: Or write two papers.  In my discipline, there are papers where the first paper has the title 'Blah blah -- Part I: Theory', and a follow-up paper entitled '..Part 2: Applications'.

Comment: Please specify a field. Conference submission standards are very field-dependent, and so are average paper lengths.

Comment: Closely related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/can-a-paper-be-submitted-to-a-journal-if-i-submit-it-to-a-conference/

Comment: You might also want to check the journal's policies on this. Some don't mind conference submissions as long as it isn't the exact same. Many do. Alternatively.. Find a better journal for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all conferences publish their results - this is a convention that is common in CS, but not all disciplines. In cases where no publication is made by the conference, it is common for articles to be both under review and under discussion at the conference.

For example, the Southern Economics Conference (SEC) does not publish the accepted papers.  It is entirely acceptable to submit papers to the SEC that are in progress, under review, or even recently published.  It is considered part of getting feedback or drumming up publicity.

Comment: Hmmm. To clarify, in CS it is the convention to publish conference papers. Indeed, it is the main venue.

Answer (score 0):

While it is improper to submit the *same* paper to different venues simultaneously, what you suggest is reasonable since the papers are not the same. It might be hard, though, to make the shorter journal article interesting enough for publication if you need to omit so much. But if the longer article is sufficiently different then it should be fine.

Make sure to cite the "earlier" work in the later one. And cross citation might be needed if the two works are too close in time.

But, another alternative might be a journal that doesn't have such a small page limit. Major works might be hard to condense sufficiently for some journals. The American Math Society, for example has journals with short papers and another with quite long ones.